# Java IO in Scala

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

I am using Scala and am trying to use Java's IO, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  Here is the basis of what I have:

```
import java.io._
object test{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
   val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.txt"))
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following:

> Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default-sbt-compile) on project SingleTableSparkScan: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

When I remove the line that uses Java's IO, everything runs fine.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you do `val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.txt"))` ? If that doesn't work, expand your post to contain a verifiable code example

Comment: yeah, you are missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: My bad, I had 'new' before but forgot it when typing this up.  And as far as sample code, I made a totally new file and was just trying to get java.io to work.  I will edit the original post with it

Comment: Error handling? Could there be an IOException occurring here?

Comment: @ManoDestra Scala does not have checked exceptions like Java so you are not required to add, for example, `throws IOException`. That's not the cause of the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php  and the code to compiles and runs.

There must be some kind of other problem with your set up

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.txt"));
```

Comment: Oops looks like i forgot to carry over the "new" from my code....I updated the original post